# Fixing one part while other rotate with camera in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glut, freeglut

Is it is possible to have a openGL window where one part is fixed and other rotate or traslate with the camera.

To be more clear.
I want a control bases screen.
I want the control(may be buttons generated in square form) to be fixed while the rest screen move with the camera.
Can any one tell me if it is feasible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this effect you need to first draw your 3D scene using a perspective projection and then switch to an orthographic projection and draw your 2D control elements.  This process is then  repeated each frame. The technique is outlined [here](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/glut/index.php3?bmpfontortho).

Comment: Thanks the example helmed me a lot

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL is not a scene graph. It's a state controlled drawing API. Things are drawn as you call OpenGL functions. It's perfectly possible to draw one thing using a set of projection and modelview matrices and viewport A then change projection, modelview and viewport to set B and draw further things.

I leave the rest to your imagination.

Big fat hint, hopefully making it click: If you set the viewport and projection in some window resize handler, move this code into the drawing code.